# How to pass value from one component to another in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a wizard component.

```
<template>
    <c-wizard header="Reset Password Wizard" variant="path" current-step="step-1" oncomplete={saveAccount}>
        <c-wizard-step label="Tell us about yourself to get started" name="step-1" before-change={step1Click}>
            <h2>Tell us about yourself to get started</h2>               
            <lightning-input label="First Name" data-field-name="FirstName" required></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input label="SSN" data-field-name="SSN" required></lightning-input>
        </c-wizard-step>
        <c-wizard-step label="What is the best way to reach you?" name="step-2" before-change={step2Click}>
            <h2>You will receive a OTP on your registered email {userEmail}</h2>
        </c-wizard-step>        
    </c-wizard>
</template>
```

What I want to do is, pass a value from wizard-step 1 to wizard-step 2. In `step1Click()` method, I will asynchronously fetch data from apex for example user userEmail and want to pass that data to the 2nd wizard-step.
What I have done in `step1Click()` is

```
@track userEmail = 'test@mail.com';
step1Click(){
        const allValid = [...this.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
            .reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
                inputCmp.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
            }, true);

        // 2 - Returns true/false; if the validation were asynchronous, it should return a Promise instead
        if(allValid) {
                this.userEmail = "noor@gmail.com";
        }
        return allValid;
    }
```

`this.userEmail` is setting here, but I cannot get this inside 2nd wizard-step

```
<c-wizard-step label="What is the best way to reach you?" name="step-2" before-change={step2Click}>
            <h2>You will receive a OTP on your registered email {userEmail}</h2>
    </c-wizard-step>
```

Why it is not working? You can find the full code [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/AUlhJ85Lpc5keCdFUPAk/src/app.html).

Comment: P.S. `@track` is no longer required on simple variables, only objects and arrays that you modify without changing memory references (e.g. Array.prototype.push).

Answer (score 1):

The method you bound, `step1Click`, is bound to the `WizardStep` class, not the `App` class, so when you set `this.userEmail`, you're actually setting the value on the `WizardStep`, not the `App`, even though the method is defined in the App class.

This is apparent because the validation you're performing is finding elements contained in the current `c-wizard-step` element, an effect caused by using `this.beforeChange.bind(this)`. If you wish to communicate with the `App` component properly, fire an event and handle it in on the `c-wizard` component. Here's an example to fix this:

```
handleDataUpdate(event) {
    Object.keys(event.detail).forEach(key => this[key] = event.detail[key]);
}
step1Click(){
    const allValid = [...this.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
        .reduce((validSoFar, inputCmp) => {
            inputCmp.reportValidity();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
        }, true);

    // 2 - Returns true/false; if the validation were asynchronous, it should return a Promise instead
    if(allValid) {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('data', { bubbles: true, detail: {userEmail: 'noor@gmail.com '}})
        );
    }
    return allValid;
}
```

And on the app markup:

```
<c-wizard ondata={handleDataUpdate} header="Reset Password Wizard" variant="path" current-step="step-1"
    oncomplete={saveAccount}>
```

This is normally how you'd handle child-parent communication anyways, but it looks "weird" because the parent is effectively sending a message to itself, but by way of the child, but this should be fine for your use case, at least for now. Obviously, no error handling is present, so you'll want to add any necessary checks.

Here's a link to the [cloned version](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/2oQ2AVN9CZcpijNEbhcy/src/app.html).